# unable to aggregate initialise a variable of type structure with bit field members wrapped in class template

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct EndianGuard_ {};
template<typename Type_>
struct EndianGuarded_ : EndianGuard_ {
  EndianGuarded_() {
    uint8_t* ByteData = (uint8_t*) this;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (Type_); i++) {
      ByteData[i] = 0;
    }
  };
  EndianGuarded_ (Type_ Value) : Value (Value) {};
  ~EndianGuarded_ () {};
  Type_ Value;
};

struct Slot_2 {
  uint8_t Slot :    4;
  uint8_t Unit :    3;
  uint8_t Bus :     2;
  uint8_t Unused :  7;
};

EndianGuarded_<Slot_2> Slot = {7, 6, 1, 0};
```

I get no instance of constructor matches given argument list `(int, int, int, int)` error.

Is it a compiler bug? My bitfield struct qualifies for aggregate initialization.

And then when I try to Aggregate initialize an `EndianGuard_` derived struct containing an array member I get the similar error though the matching constructor is defined.

```
struct ProtocolResult_ : EndianGuard_ {
  ProtocolResult_(const EndianGuarded_<char> Value[2]) {
    this->Value[0] = Value[0];
    this->Value[1] = Value[1];
  };

  static const ProtocolResult_
  NORMAL_ANSWER,
  BUSY;

  EndianGuarded_<char> Value[2];
};
const ProtocolResult_ ProtocolResult_:: // no matching constructor with arguments
NORMAL_ANSWER =    {{'0', '0' }},       // ({...})
BUSY =             { '1', '1' };        // (char, char)
```

Comment: What is `T_`? Should it be `Type_`?

Comment: Thanks! How come I didn't notice!

Comment: FYI: If you want to force zero-initialization when default constructing the object, you don't need to actually write zeros to the data structure (which is seriously undefined behavior BTW). Simply do this: `EndianGuarded_() : EndianGuard_{}, Value{} {}`

Answer (score 1):

`EndianGuarded_` is not an aggregate. Aggregates have no constructors, and this type has constructors. Therefore, list initialization syntax will attempt to call constructors, based on the parameters you provide.

Also, even if you ditched the constructors, `EndianGuarded_` still wouldn't be an aggregate by the rules of C++ before 17. Why? Because aggregates cannot have base classes, and yours does.

And *even if* this were C++17, `EndianGuarded_` doesn't have 4 subobjects. It has 2; the base class `EndianGuard_` and the member subobject `Value_`. So you would need to initialize it would something like `{{/*whatever goes to the base class}, {7, 6, 1, 0}}`.

Answer (score 1):

`EndianGuard_` definition is missing in your example, so I am adding it as an empty struct. Each of the following three initializations would compile with C++11:

```
struct EndianGuard_ { };

template<typename Type_>
struct EndianGuarded_ : EndianGuard_ {
  EndianGuarded_ (Type_ Value) : Value (Value) {};
 private:
  Type_ Value;
};

struct Slot_2 {
  int Slot :    4;
  int Unit :    3;
  int Bus :     2;
  int Unused :  7;
};

EndianGuarded_<Slot_2> SlotX = {{7, 6, 1, 0}};
EndianGuarded_<Slot_2> SlotY({7, 6, 1, 0});
EndianGuarded_<Slot_2> SlotZ = Slot_2 {7, 6, 1, 0};
```

The initialization of `SlotY` is arguably the most readable, as it implicitly shows that you are calling the constructor that takes one argument (outer `()`), and this constructor takes the aggregate-initialized struct (inner `{}`).

The `SlotZ` initialization uses implicit type conversion. Mark the constructor `explicit`, and it would fail. Google C++ style, for one, requires one-argument constructors be marked `explicit`, because they can cause surprises like this one. But YMMV.